# I need to update the Recipient to relevant role in Docusign

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Let me say for the example. I have created 4 role such as Signer1, Signer2, Signer3 and Signer4 in template. Also, I assigned the Signature and Date signed tag to each role and saved the template.

Now i need to send docusign to recipient from Salesforce as i did below steps.

- Clicked on Send with Docusign.
- From Documents, Selected Docusign Template.
- From Recipients, Clicked on Quick Add and Added 4 recipient with
  above 4 role.

Here i need to update recipient with predefined Recipient Role in Template. But unable to update the new recipient to predefined role.

Thanks in Advance.
Raja.